# $watch not working on modal using $ekathuwa module angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement a $scope.$watch on a modal using Ekathuwa module, https://github.com/sarath2/ngEkathuwa. It's not working. I had include a console.log() to get an idea why it is not functioning that way it supposed to be. I'm getting an undefined value on $scope.dealer. This is the ng-model of the dropdown selection from the modal template that is being watch. Below is the code. I hope someone can help me with it. Thanks in advance

```
myApp.controller('ordersCtrl', 
    function ordersCtrl($scope, ngTableParams, dealerData, $http, $ekathuwa, $rootScope, $location, userService, $filter){

    if(!$rootScope.isLogged){
        $location.path('/').replace();
    } else {
        dealerData.getDealers(function(dealers){
            $scope.dealers = dealers;
        });

        $scope.$watch("filter.$", function () {
            $scope.tableParams.reload();
        });

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10,          // count per page
            sorting: {
                name: 'asc'     // initial sorting
            }
        }, {
            getData: function($defer, params) {     

                $http.get('api/wos').
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                        var filteredData = $filter('filter')(data, $scope.filter);
                        var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                                        $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, params.orderBy()) :
                                        filteredData;

                    $scope.data = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                    params.total(orderedData.length);
                    $defer.resolve($scope.data);
                });

            },
            $scope: $scope
        });

        $scope.addWorkOrder = function(){           
            $scope.modalHeader = "ADD NEW WORK ORDER";
            $scope.modalType = "Add";
            $ekathuwa.modal({
                id: "modalWO",
                scope: $scope,
                templateURL: "./tpl/modal-wo.html"
            });

            console.log("Modal : "+ $scope.dealer +" is working");

            $scope.$watch('dealer', function(newDealer, oldDealer){
                if ( newDealer === oldDealer) {
                    return;
                }

                console.log("$watch : "+ $scope.dealer +" is working");

                $http.get('api/profile/'+$scope.dealer).
                    success(function(data, status, headers, config){

                        $scope.outletno = data.outletno;
                        $scope.address = data.address;
                        $scope.ae_engineer = data.name;
                        $scope.assignment = data.assignment;
                        $scope.dname = data.dname;
                });

                if ($scope.dealer === newDealer) {
                    return;
                }


            });

        }

        $scope.logout = function(){
            userService.setAuthentication(false);
            console.log(userService.getAuthentication());
            $location.path('/').replace();
        }
    }
});
```

The HTML:

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Select Dealer:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">      
                                <select class="form-control" 
                                        ng-model="dealer" 
                                        required="required"
                                        ng-options="option.sskey as option.dname for option in dealers" >
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Did you solve the problem?